# Reading data from .txt file and calculating mean in Python

Tags: python, input, average, mean

I have a question about my Python code.
I would like to read data from a `.txt` file and calculate the average of these values. The format of the `.txt` file is (1 vertical column):

```
1.36
5.5
6.11
12.05
25.8
38.28
```

The code that I have written is:

```
 from statistics import mean

 with open('inputdata.txt','r') as fin:
     data=fin.read().split('\n')
     for index in range(len(data)):
         average=mean(float(index))

  print(average)
```

I used the above code, but in command window shows the following message:

```
if iter(data) is data:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: If i do this command window shows me:  TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator

Comment: Iterate over `data` and make a float of each number; pass *the whole thing* to `mean` -  `average = mean(float(n) for n in data)`.

Comment: Now it works !!! Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of values by splitting by '\n' and convert those values to float, after that you can calculate the mean of that list using the mean from statistics:

```
from statistics import mean

with open('inputdata.txt','r') as fin:
    data=[float(x) for x in fin.read().split('\n')]

average = mean(data)
print(average)
```

Comment: a verbal explanation would be a very helpful addition to your answer